# Get workspace of a running instance of Eclipse w/ command line

Tags: linux, eclipse, shell

Using the command line on Linux, is it possible to get absolute paths of workspaces where instances of Eclipse are currently running?

Something like:

```
shell-command-line
    /workspace/number/one
    /workspace/number/two
```

Comment: how about using `pwd`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't indicate if Eclipse is running. I was thinking about using `ps aux | grep eclipse`, which doesn't work neither.